# Creating a throw-away database copy in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, snapshot

Is it possible to create a throw-away database snapshot/copy in SQL Server 2008?

I want to be able to spin up a local version of a report generator we use (custom app) and have it operate on a copy of the data at the moment of the snapshot. The problem is that this report generator writes to the database, so I can't use the normal snapshot feature since those are read-only. (Yes I know that it's stupid to have the report generator write to the db, but I inherited the project ;) )

When I'm done doing the testing, I want to just erase everything I just did.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a database snapshot:

```
CREATE DATABASE SnapshotName ON
    (  
    NAME = YourDatabase_Data, 
    FILENAME = 'c:\path\to\snapshot.ss'
    )
    AS SNAPSHOT OF YourDatabase;
```

Instead of working on the snapshot, work on the original database.

When you're done, revert the database to the snapshot state:

```
RESTORE DATABASE YourDatabase FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = 'SnapshotName';
```

Comment: Only if the original database does not get any other writes from the app. Also restore from snapshot breaks the log chain, with dire consequences.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: "breaking the log chain" would only be relevant if you tried to restore log backups that were made after the snapshot?

Comment: No the DB needs to be "clean" because I'm working in a production environment (i know i know)

Comment: breaking the log chain breaks log shipping and requires a new full backup. This may or may not be hard to do, but is very important to realize that is required to do